# Mod Rewrite Easy problem with Cookies

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm trying to catch all the non-logged-in users who are trying to get to a directory (where my .htaccess is placed). If someone is not logged-in and try to access some page in this directory, it will be redirected to page "`user/?login=222`"
A user is logged-in, when the Cookie "HDV-UL" starts with a 5 digit number.

This is my .htaccess:

```
# Working with Apache 1.3
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !HDV-UL=[0-9]{5}-[^;]+;
RewriteRule .* /user/?login=222 [R,L]
```

This is not working, any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !HDV-UL=[0-9]{5}-[^;]+
RewriteRule !^user/$ /user/?login=222 [R,L]
```

I removed the trailing `;` as it’s only present if there are multiple cookies and I excluded the target of the redirect to avoid a redirection loop.